# wpdb select query to get meta_value return zero

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field name "ipnrm-meta-panorama-theme". I want to get meta_value of it. For this task I use this query for test

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
          "SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta " .
          "WHERE post_id = %d and meta_key = %s", 
          $post->ID, "ipnrm-meta-panorama-theme" ) );
echo $result;
```

The result is 0.
But if I change the meta_key parameter to "_edit_lock" in the query

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
          "SELECT count(*) FROM $wpdb->postmeta " .
          "WHERE post_id = %d and meta_key = %s", 
          $post->ID, "_edit_lock" ) );
echo $result;
```

The result is 1.
I check the wp_postmeta table via a db editor and my custom field is exist.
How it could be, I do not understand yet?

Comment: It`s your return 0 or null ? get_var return the database query result (as string), or null on failure!

Comment: It returns 0. I use count(*) for the test only, not for production.

Comment: the problem is in your sql query, the rest is fine, have you a datbase entry with the post_id and the meta_key! Can you give me the reult of the database query from the database direct?

Comment: I tested with direct sql  `SELECT count(*) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = 3295 and meta_key = 'ipnrm-meta-panorama-theme'` It returns 1, the record is exist unlike wpdb.

Comment: I found a problem the $post->ID is incorrect.

Comment: perfect :) , i hope you have now the right result

Comment: why you are not using standard wordpress function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ ?